Sci-fi TV episode about man who calculates future
I'm remembering a specific episode, which I thought was from X-files, but I can't find it based on the episode descriptions on wikipedia or by search.
They are tracking down someone who can predict/calculate probable futures. Two specific scenes that I remember are:

at some point they have captured this guy, and are transporting in the back of an armored truck, but through an elaborate sequence of improbable events he is freed (ie, spilled coffee causes driver to hit pothole, causes gun to go off, which breaks free his handcuffs)
the final scene is of a leaf falling from the sky, and he is able to predict exactly where it would fall.

This is similar to these other movies/shows:

Next (Nicholas Cage)
Ink (movie, stop the flow)
Fringe S03E03 (Plateau) 

It is not the x-files 'The Goldberg Variation'

could it be Paycheck (2003) ? It has the predict future and chasing element. But not fit your description.

no, this episode was definitely 'calculating' possible future based on probabilities/physics, not just looking into the future and acting based on that knowledge

Not exactly as you describe, but it reminds me of the Fringe episode "The Plateau" in which a man can calculate the outcome of events.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plateau_(Fringe)

Men in Black 3 has a character (Griffin) who can see all possible futures, and makes choices based on which future he is going to wind up in. However, the movie you're describing sounds much more serious, and MIB3 did not end with a leaf falling from the sky. There was a meteor falling from the sky that was going to destroy the earth, but Agent K leaves a tip and that somehow leads to the meteor hitting a satellite and being destroyed.

no, it wasn't MIB3

@Tim, the Fringe episode was already mentioned in the question. What I'm remembering is extremely close to that type of plot (man can calculate/factor all variables to determine future actions), but I watched that episode and it's definitely not it.

Could it be Alphas ep02s01 "Cause and Effect"?
It focuses on the ex-patient of Dr. Rosen, Marcus Ayers, an alpha who 

possesses powerful  calculative abilities allowing him to predict future events and manipulate cause and effect. He can cause massive changes in any environment or system with little to no effort by simply examining it and understanding the effect his actions and the actions of others will take. (from the wiki)

The episode begins when he escapes an ambulance/truck. There is also a scene with a leaf, when 

 Marcus meets Dr Rosen and shows him exactly where a leaf will fall. 

I don't think it's the end scene though.

Yes, this is it. I just re-watched to confirm. He's handcuffed in the ambulance and escapes, and then the leaf scene is shortly afterwards (not the ending scene like I thought)
